# Beginner- Python Panadas - How to know time spent across Rank and sub level for an employee

Tags: python, pandas, count, sum, average

I am  trying to see "how much time each employee has spent  on his/her Rank and levels".
The dataset consists of employee tenure i.e. if an employee is active for 5 months then 5 records would be available.
Below is the dataset

```
Employee  Month        Rank   Level
A         01-07-2022   10       1
A         01-09-2022   10       1
A         01-08-2022   10       1
A         01-10-2022   10       2
A         01-12-2022   10       3 
A         01-01-2023   11       1 
B         01-07-2022   07       1
B         01-09-2022   07       1
B         01-08-2022   09       4
B         01-10-2022   09       2
B         01-12-2022   11       3 
B         01-01-2023   12       1
```

Code:

```py
 df= df.groupby(['Employee','Rank','Level'])['Rank']\
       .count()\
       .to_frame('Tenure_rank_grade').reset_index()
```

But the above code gives the count, however, the expected is time spent.
How can this be achievable?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output in short is for employee A : 108 days times spent on respective level and Rank.. And so on for all the employees

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) combined with [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
delta = -df.sort_values(by='Month').groupby('Employee')['Month'].diff(-1)
out = (df.assign(total_time=delta)
         .groupby(['Employee', 'Rank', 'Level'])
         .sum()
      )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
                    total_time
Employee Rank Level           
A        10   1        92 days
              2        61 days
              3        31 days
         11   1         0 days
B        7    1        61 days
         9    2        61 days
              4        31 days
         11   3        31 days
         12   1         0 days
```

If you want to include the count to the current day instead of 0 for the current position:

```
delta = (df.sort_values(by='Month')
           .groupby('Employee')['Month']
           .apply(lambda s: -s.diff(-1).fillna(s.max()-pd.Timestamp('today').floor('D')))
        )

out = (df.assign(total_time=delta)
         .groupby(['Employee', 'Rank', 'Level'])
         .sum()
      )
```

Output:

```
                    total_time
Employee Rank Level           
A        10   1        92 days
              2        61 days
              3        31 days
         11   1        11 days
B        7    1        61 days
         9    2        61 days
              4        31 days
         11   3        31 days
         12   1        11 days
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have  few questions.. when i tried e the  above  code , i see no errors however no total_time column been assigned. Here df data frame i have given 3 columns however in the original dataframe there are almost  30 columns too .So how can i append this total_time column to the existing columns that i have in my df dataframe? as currently i dont see " total_time" column

Comment: Unable to share a screenshot however it looks something like this post running the code.     - Employee   Rank   Level  Age Companies Feedback >>>> these are all other columns which are there is the original dataframe .And here after running teh code dont see time_Spent column appended

Comment: Unable to share a screenshot however it looks something like this post running the code.     - Employee   Rank   Level  Age Companies Feedback >>>> these are all other columns which are there is the original dataframe .And here after running teh code dont see time_Spent column appended

Comment: This doesn't affect you original DataFrame, but creates a new DataFrame. You can either merge it or assign with `transform('sum')` instead of `sum`

Comment: Thank you .A doubt i see that irrespective of transform('sum) or sum , the columns are varying i.e. not having the original  count of columns. out = (df.assign(total_time=delta)
         .groupby(['Employee', 'Rank', 'Level'])
         .transform('sum')
      ) .........The df column has 37 columns and the out column is having 17 columns. what is making the decrease?

Comment: And also the if i have to merge with df and out dataframe, here the primary key to be used for merging is Employee, but after running the above code the Employee column isnt available also all the columns data in the out dataframe  got corrupted too .

Comment: To be something like this: DF dataframe=   employee  Total_time  Rank Level etc etc etc etc etc etc(etc refers to original columns from original dataframe)